# Pass context this as parameter in custom validator

Tags: angular, typescript

I trying passing a class property in custom async validator but its value still always `undefined` when i log it from this validator...

From CustomValidators.js :

```
static isValidPlace(place: Place, controlName: string): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: FormControl): Observable<{ [key: string]: boolean }> => {
      console.log('control', control.value);
      console.log('place', place);

      if (place && place.label !== control.value)
        return Observable.of({ 'invalidPlace': true });

      return Observable.empty();
    }
}
```

From component :

```
city: FormControl = this.fb.control(
  '', 
  Validators.required, 
  CustomValidators.isValidPlace(this.citySelection, 'city').bind(this)
);
```

And I attached (change) event on field which fire the following fn :

```
onSelectionCity = (selection: Place): Place => this.citySelection = selection;
```

---

Question : How can I pass updated `citySelection` property through my custom validator ?

---

What I want to do :

I need an id which sent by api when the user clicks on a result list which itself depends on the value typed in a formControl (input).

The problem is, when the user change the value, I have to consider formControl invalid because the only way for validate the input field is to clicks on a list for getting an id. Meanwhile if the value change, the id become incorrect, i want apply this behavior.

Exemple: Imagine a Google search engine a little bit different with the famous button "search". 
In fact, when you'll write something inside the search field and a list'll be display. Now you clicks on one of the items.

Now imagine one second than the button need an id to search the correct information and this id is getting the clicks event fired.

You have your id its great, but change the text, the input field have to be invalid because the id you got previously is different of your potential new search asking.

My suggestion is to compare the full Object which contains label, id and other stuffs `selectionCity` saved on my component class on clicks event with the actual value of the formControl to determine the validity by simple triple comparaison.

Comment: This brings an important question : **why would you do that**.

Comment: @trichetriche please look above, i written something for u

Comment: So basically, you want to validate with an ID that is updated ?

Comment: yes.

The user write : "Paris", i have a list of items.

The user clicks on "Paris Xe arrondissement" i store on the class `selectionCity` which contains : `{ id: 555, label: 'Paris Xe arrondissement', ... }`
The custom validator compare `formControl.value` with `selectionCity.label`

Comment: Instead of binding your component to the validator, why don't you just recreate the form control with an updated validator ?

Comment: Hum you mean something like :
`
onChangeValue = () => (
  this.myForm.controls['controlName']
    .clearValidators()
    .setValidators(CustomValidators.isValidPlace(this.citySelection, 'city').bind(this))
)
`

?

Comment: That's the idea, only without the `bind` at the end.

Comment: I see, thank's you I'm going to try :)

Comment: If you need help, I'm still there ! (et même en français si besoin)

Comment: Ah j'aurai du m'en douté avec un pseudo pareil :) merci je vais tenter quelques trucs et je reviens vers toi ^^

Comment: Bon ba niquel @trichetriche merci beaucoup !

Comment: Si tu veux que up vote ta réponse tu devrais répondre via "Answer the question" :)

Comment: Pas de souci, c'est fait !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to bind your component to the validator, you should instead recreate the form control or update its validators once your ID changes.

```
onValueChange = () => {
  this.myForm.controls['controlName']
    .clearValidators() 
    .setValidators([
      Validators.required,
      CustomValidators.isValidPlace(this.citySelection, 'city')
  ]);
}
```